# What is the relationship between the asymptotic series outside the radius of convergence and the analytic continuation?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, analytic-continuation

In [his post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) about computing the zeta function by smooth cutoff regularization of the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$, Terry Tao shows how $-{1\over 12}$ is the finite part of the asymptotic series for the smooth cutoff regularization of the sum $\sum\frac{1}{n}$. In the last section of his post, he justifies why that value should match the analytic continuation of the function from its convergent domain. While all the steps of that argument make sense, I am somehow missing the larger picture. Can someone attempt another explanation?

Let's make my question more concrete. If $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ is absolutely convergent for $\lvert z\rvert < R$ with a pole at some $z_0$, $\lvert z_0\rvert = R$, and has analytic continuation $\tilde f(z)$ defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus z_0$, is there some standard way to break $f$ into an asymptotic series, with a demarcated finite part and infinite part? Like $f(z)\sim\sum_{n=1}^N b_n\epsilon^{-n} +\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\epsilon^n$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, and with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\epsilon^n\to \tilde f(z)$. If we discard the divergent part, the finite part matches the analytic continuation. Why? This is what Tao does, and seems to also match the approach of some shady QFT maneuvers.

Comment: "this is what Tao does". can you point me to where?

Comment: also, you have $f(z) \sim $ stuff but there's no $z$ in the stuff

Comment: @mathworker21 The link to Tao's post is in my post, but here it is again: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/. And I hope a correct explanation of the asymptotics of a divergent series would tell us the relationship between $z$ and $\epsilon$. But I'm assuming $\epsilon$ should maybe be "how far is $z$ past the pole" or something

Comment: I obviously saw the link. I'm asking where in there he does what u said "this is what Tao does"

Comment: @mathworker21 In the first half of the post, he does some calculus to compute the regularized value of the sum. Makes sense, it's just calculus. Then in the second half of the post, titled "connection with analytic continuation", I think he explains my title question: why is the analytic continuation past the pole equal to the regularized divergent sum past the pole (up to a term). He explained it I think, but I didn't really understand.

Comment: I can see that my question is not really well-formed and it's not clear what a correct answer should even look like. I will think about how I can make it clearer and more concrete.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm fine with vague/[intuition-based] questions. I just wanted to know which math you wanted intuition for. I will try my best to come back to this soon.